# Change Wicket tree node colour, font, etc

Tags: fonts, colors, wicket, treenode

Is there a way to change the nodes colour and change it to italic, etc.?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. We would be able to give better answers if you explained what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this thread](http://markmail.org/message/rijmypqgky7klubv) will help you, even though that asker seems to be looking for a little more than you are. From Edvin's replies:

> If you override the `populateTreeItem()` method, you can add an `AbstractBehaviour` to the item and override the `onComponentTag` method. From there you can do
>
> ```
> tag.put("class", "yourValue")
> ```
>
> ...
>
> you need to add an `AbstractBehaviour` to each item. The `onComponentTag()` method will be run before the component is rendered, so you can check the state of your `userObject` and add/remove classes using the `tag.put()` approach :)
>
> Also, you might look into `onNodeLinkClicked()` method of the tree, if you want to perform actions when you click on an item. The `onNodeLinkClicked()` gives you access to the `AjaxRequestTarget`, so you can also execute arbitrary JavaScript code, like this:
>
> ```
> protected void onNodeLinkClicked(AjaxRequestTarget target, TreeNode node) {
>     MyObject myObject = (MyObject)
>       ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) node).getUserObject();
>     if (myObject.getMyState())
>         target.appendJavascript("targetTheComponentWithAJavascriptMethod(" +
>           getId() + ");");
> }
> ```
>
> Either that, or you could change the state of the `userObject` in the `onNodeLinkClicked` method and add it to the `AjaxRequestTarget`. Your `AbstractBehaviour` will then take care of visualizing the new state of the object for you :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I have come accross this. I have done little javascript before so i am unsure what to add to this.

Comment: @Matthew, well, if you don't want dynamic changes, you don't need to worry about JavaScript at all. You can just set a boring old CSS class and be done. But again, it's very unclear from your question what you're actually trying to do. Please edit it to add more details using the link under the tags.

Comment: in a wicket tree i am trying to make a node at the top of the tree(hard coded not dynamic) a different colour to the rest of the tree. So the top node would be red and italics for example.

Answer (score 0):

You want to extend `TreeTable` and then override `getCss()` to change fonts and text or background colors. If you want to change the colors of the actual node icons you want to override `getNodeIcon()` and add resources for your own PNG files.

```
public abstract class MyTreeTable extends TreeTable {
    private static ResourceReference CSS = new CompressedResourceReference(
        MyTreeTable.class, "TreeTable.css");
    private static ResourceReference documentIcon = new CompressedResourceReference(
        MyTreeTable.class, "Icon_Document.png");
    private static ResourceReference folderIcon = new CompressedResourceReference(
        MyTreeTable.class, "Icon_Folder.png");

    public MyTreeTable(String id, IColumn[] columns) {
        super(id, columns);
    }

    @Override
    protected ResourceReference getCSS() {
        return CSS;
    }

    @Override
    protected ResourceReference getNodeIcon(TreeNode node) {
        if (node.isLeaf() == true) {
            return documentIcon;
        } else {
            return folderIcon;
        }
    }
}
```

The CSS for this particular component is very finicky because they use a single image and image-offsets for all the lines connecting the tree, so I recommend copying their whole CSS file (you can get it from the source files) and then adjusting it. Or, if you don't want to make extensive changes you may want to not override `getCSS()` at all and instead add your CSS resource in the constructor.

The really truly super lame part is that `TreeTable` inserts an invisible div at the top of each table, so the `:first-child` pseudo class can't be used to select your item, or at least, I cannot seem to make it work.  So you will still need to override `populateTreeItem()`. Something like:

```
boolean first = true;
@Override
protected void populateTreeItem(WebMarkupContainer container, int level) {
    super.populateItem(container, level);
    if(first) {
        container.add(new SimpleAttributeModifer("class", "first"));
        first = false;
    }
}
```

and then in your CSS,

```
.first {font-color: red; font-style: italic;}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `LinkTree` (deprecated in Wicket 6.21 or even earlier) you can override the `newNodeComponent` method to build component from scratch:

```
@Override
protected Component newNodeComponent(String id, IModel<Object> model)
{
    Object node = model.getObject();
    if (node instanceof FolderNode)
    {
        FolderNode folderNode = (FolderNode)node;
        return new Label(id, folderNode.getLabel());
    }
    else if (node instanceof FileNode)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if ...
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note: original implementation builds `LinkIconPanel` with the `LinkTree#onNodeLinkClicked()` handler called automatically. To preserve this feature, you have to call `onNodeLinkClicked()` manually in your custom link's handler.